# Keep asking until input is correct

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a small game with 3 different options, but i'm not sure how to write this in code: 
            if answer isn't 1,2 or 3, keep asking the question untill the input is 1,2 or 3.

```
        Console.WriteLine("What do you want to do?");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Eat");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Drink");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Play");
        string answer = Console.ReadLine();

        if (answer == "1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("you picked number 1");
        }
        if (answer == "2")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You picked number 2");
        }
        if (answer == "3")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You picked number 3");
        }
        // if answer isn't 1,2 or 3, keep asking the question untill the input is correct.
```

Comment: you need a while loop

Comment: Surprising you did not find any examples of doing so. Possibly search engine you are using is just bad - try using [Google](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=C%23+Keep+asking+untill+input+is+correct) of [Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+Keep+asking+untill+input+is+correct) before asking question in the future. Even if you will not get immediate answers it could help with showing what approaches you've tried and why/how that did not work.

Answer (score 2):

```
  var answer="";
  while(true)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("What do you want to do?");
    Console.WriteLine("1. Eat");
    Console.WriteLine("2. Drink");
    Console.WriteLine("3. Play");
    answer = Console.ReadLine();

    if (answer == "1")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("you picked number 1");
        break;
    }
    if (answer == "2")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You picked number 2");
        break;
    }
    if (answer == "3")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You picked number 3");
        break;
    }
  }
```

or

```
  var answer="";
  while(answer!="1" && answer!="2" && answer!="3")
  {
    Console.WriteLine("What do you want to do?");
    Console.WriteLine("1. Eat");
    Console.WriteLine("2. Drink");
    Console.WriteLine("3. Play");
    answer = Console.ReadLine();

    if (answer == "1")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("you picked number 1");
    }
    if (answer == "2")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You picked number 2");
    }
    if (answer == "3")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You picked number 3");
    }
  }
```

or

```
  var answer="";
  var validanswers = new [] {"1","2","3"};
  while(!validanswers.Contains(answer))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("What do you want to do?");
    Console.WriteLine("1. Eat");
    Console.WriteLine("2. Drink");
    Console.WriteLine("3. Play");
    answer = Console.ReadLine();

    if (answer == "1")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("you picked number 1");
    }
    if (answer == "2")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You picked number 2");
    }
    if (answer == "3")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You picked number 3");
    }
  }
```

Comment: I assume that he will be replacing that to call different functions, and those are just placeholders.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
string answer = String.Empty;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("What do you want to do?");
    Console.WriteLine("1. Eat");
    Console.WriteLine("2. Drink");
    Console.WriteLine("3. Play");
    answer = Console.ReadLine();
} while (answer != "1" && answer != "2" && answer != "3");

//handle answer here
```